# What would be the best way to weight paint this character with a lot of layered clothing?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, weight-painting

I recently modeled this character and when adding a rig, the clothes overlap, or the automatic weights add unnecessary paint to parts of the coat. I know basic weight painting.

[image]

Comment: There is an addon for this problem: Voxel Skinning: https://blendermarket.com/products/voxel-heat-diffuse-skinning Not free, but works perfectly, I tried it.

Comment: Thank you very much will check this out!